# Server Publishing infrastructure not enabled on newly created sites by default?

Tags: 2013, publishing

I just updated our master page on 2013 so that breadcrumbs will start showing.  I clicked to have all sites inherite the master file which worked like a champ.  I noticed though that any new site being created does not seem to have this master file applied.  After doing some digging I realized that any new site has the publishing infrastructure deactivated.

Once I activate it the breadcrumbs show and everything looks good.

Is there a way to have this turned on by default so that any new site gets this setting or am I possibly setting up the master page wrong and that's why its seems to not be applied by default when the site is setup?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The publishing infrastructure is not enabled by default on new Team sites unless you specify the site collection as being a Publishing Site instead.

In the past, people would create feature receivers and deploy them to the farm to look for site creations, then apply customizations automatically. There are other ways to accomplish this in 2013, the Patterns and Practices groups has some provisioning options on their github repo, https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP.